# 'gunicorn' is not recognized as an internal or external command with Heroku Local

Tags: python, heroku, gunicorn

I'm trying to run the command `heroku local` when following the section **Push Local Changes** in the tutorial:
[Heroku Python Tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#push-local-changes)

I'm getting the error:

> [OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format 18:51:47 web.1   |
> 'gunicorn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> 18:51:47 web.1   |  operable program or batch file. [DONE] Killing all
> processes with signal  SIGINT 18:51:47 web.1   Exited with exit code
> null

I tried searching online but I haven't found anything useful.
Does someone have an idea how to solve this error?

**EDIT:**
I have successfully implemented all the previous steps of the tutorial, and if I run CMD in the folder `C:\python-getting-started` and run the command `pip list`, the dependencies are:

```
Package         Version
--------------- ---------
asgiref         3.2.10
certifi         2020.6.20
chardet         3.0.4
dj-database-url 0.5.0
Django          3.0.8
django-heroku   0.3.1
gunicorn        20.0.4
idna            2.10
pip             20.2
psycopg2        2.8.5
pytz            2020.1
requests        2.24.0
setuptools      41.2.0
sqlparse        0.3.1
urllib3         1.25.10
whitenoise      5.1.0
```

Thanks

Comment: What does "if I show the dependencies" mean? What are you doing to see that list of packages?

Comment: @Chris thanks, please see edit.

Comment: Do you have a file named `requirements.txt` and if so what is its content?

Comment: Yes I have the file with contents: `django gunicorn django-heroku requests`. I also ran the command previously according to the tutorial `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Please see post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63189816/issues-running-cmd-command-requirements-txt-with-postgres-for-heroku-development?noredirect=1#comment111782018_63189816

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the former step [Run app locally](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#run-the-app-locally), We can see the following information:

```
If you’re on Microsoft Windows system, run this:

heroku local web -f Procfile.windows
...
Just like Heroku, heroku local examines the Procfile to determine what to run.
```

Meaning, Windows requires the `-f Procfile.windows` flag.
Please try running `heroku local -f Procfile.windows`.